# using partials with express in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, partials

I am trying to render partials using node.js. Here is my code.

app.js:

```
  var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

var products = require('./products.js');

app.get('/products', function(req, res) {
    res.render('products/index', {locals: {
               products: products.all
               }
               });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I go to localhost:3000/products it should render index.jade which is in the products folder which is in the views folder.Above I set the views directory using `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`

index.jade:

```
h1 Products:
#products!= partial('partials/product', {collection: products})
```

This should render the partial equivalent to (partials/product.jade) because jade is my view engine.

I am getting an error back saying "partial is not defined"

Any help would be great. thanks

UPDATE:

That solved my partial error thank you. I reinstalled 2.5.9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what version of Express JS you have installed -- you may have the 3.0 alpha:

```
$ npm ls
...
└─┬ express@3.0.0alpha1
...
```

If you're interested in trying the alpha, be sure to checkout the documentation on [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x). In it, you'll notice that `res.partial()` and `partial()` (within templates) have been removed -- as described under "View system changes:"

> By removing the concept of a "layout" & partials in Express 3.x template engines will have greater control over file I/O. This means integration with template engines much easier, and greatly simplify the view system's internals.

You can see an example of the intent in the linked article, [Use Jade blocks, not layouts](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/).

If you're not interested, then just make sure you have 2.x installed.

```
$ npm install express@2.x
```

Or via `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "express": "2.x"
    }
}
```

Comment: `npm express -v` for just the version of express if you have a lot of packages installed